# addRange() adds last range to current one. Whats the javascript only solution?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to select text & use it for a color picker. However, when opening the color picker, the selected text loses focus, making things difficult.
My solution so far is to save the text selection, then try to re-instate the selection back onto the text.

So in the code below - first I am trying to get a range of selected text in a mouseup event.
Then I am trying to re-select the same text using the same range in another function.

It all works, except for the fact that when I try to select the text a second time, it adds the last range on top of the current range.

For example, if I select 4 letters, it reselects 4 letters. Then I click on the text again and select 5 letters; this time, it selects 9 letters. If I continue with another selection, say 3 letters, now it will select 4+9+3 letters.

Here's my code:

```
// AN ELEMENT
let changeTarget = document.createElement('div');
changeTarget.id = 'changeTarget';
document.body.append(changeTarget);
changeTarget.innerText = "Sampletext";

let currentTextSelectionStart;
let currentTextSelectionEnd;

// GET SELECTION

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){

if(window.getSelection().toString()){

let selection = window.getSelection();
currentTextSelectionStart = selection.anchorOffset;
currentTextSelectionEnd = selection.focusOffset;

console.log('start at postion', currentTextSelectionStart, 'in node', selection.anchorNode.wholeText)
console.log('stop at position', currentTextSelectionEnd, 'in node', selection.focusNode.wholeText)

}
});


// SET SELECTION

setTextSelection(changeTarget);

function setTextSelection(object) {

// First give the object focus.
object.focus();

// Next create a range.
let range = document.createRange();

// Set the range start and end.
range.setStart(object.firstChild,1);
range.setEnd(object.lastChild,4);

// Remove all previous ranges.
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();

// Add the new range.
window.getSelection().addRange(range);

}
```

I have searched for a couple of days, tried everything, but I am a newby to this so I haven't found any solution. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help/input.

Comment: Why don't you just create a clone of the range, save that, and reapply it later?

Comment: Hi somethinghere. Thanks for the suggestion, but when I tried cloning it. It does the same thing. Seems that the problem is in setStart() & setEnd(). I've even tried resetting them to 0 etc. It just does not work for some reason.

Comment: I tend to use `selection.empty()` instead of `selection.removeAllRanges()`, does that make any difference?